# Content edit page not loading

Tags: database, nodes

I have one content type with entity reference as one of the fields in the content type.
For example say that content type is 'Books'

When I open content add page for content type 'Books' its working perfectly. But the issue starts when I try to open edit page with content type 'Book' that node is having more than 17k+ users assigned as entity reference. This page stops loading after some time.

Please suggest me way to optimized this database query.

Comment: Rather than relating one node to 17k+ users, better to relate 17k+ users to one node.

Comment: Is your widget is **select list** .?

Comment: @Abin, my widget is Autocomplete.

Comment: @DavidThomas, how can I achieve node selection on user info page. Please suggest. Can we discuss more in details in chat. ?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45638/drupal-query